# PHP CURL: problems signing in to Hotmail

Tags: php, http, curl, libcurl, hotmail

I've killed lots of time on this and now I am running out of debugging options. If anyone has encountered this problem before or even simply has a slight idea of what can be going wrong, please let me know.

First of all, I use CURL to visit this page
http://login.live.com/login.srf?id=2&vv=400&lc=1033
I parse out all hidden and not hidden fields, attach login/pass, urlencode everythiong and then submit this data to the page which the sign in form points to. Then I try to find the "email/pass are wrong" error and if not, I assume that it signed in successfully. Here's the flow that takes place after this. The first entry is the response of "sign in" page (when I post all data to it).

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 571
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 08 Jul 2011 09:52:05 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Set-Cookie: MSPOK= ; expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT;domain=login.live.com;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
Set-Cookie: PPAuth=...cookie goes here...; domain=login.live.com;secure= ;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
Set-Cookie: PPLState=1; domain=.live.com;path=/;version=1
Set-Cookie: MSPShared=1; expires=Wed, 30-Dec-2037 16:00:00 GMT;domain=login.live.com;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
Set-Cookie: MSPPre= ;domain=login.live.com;path=/;Expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: MSPCID= ; HTTPOnly= ; domain=login.live.com;path=/;Expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: RPSTAuth=...cookie goes here...; domain=.live.com;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
Set-Cookie: RPSTAuthTime=1310118785; domain=login.live.com;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
Set-Cookie: MSPAuth=...cookie goes here...; domain=.live.com;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
Set-Cookie: MSPProf=...cookie goes here...; domain=.live.com;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
Set-Cookie: MSNPPAuth=...cookie goes here...; domain=.live.com;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
Set-Cookie: MH=MSFT; domain=.live.com;path=/;version=1
Set-Cookie: MHW=; expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT;domain=.live.com;path=/;version=1
Set-Cookie: MHList=; expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT;domain=.live.com;path=/;version=1
Set-Cookie: NAP=V=1.9&E=b13&C=0G_duhr_tQKqjDgf383QrDgK2gMYHsFPE_oAbIgZoDUzSr3M7_FXfw&W=1;domain=.live.com;path=/
Set-Cookie: ANON=A=A84CB86...FFFFFFF&E=b6d&W=1;domain=.live.com;path=/
Set-Cookie: MSPVis=$2$9;domain=login.live.com;path=/
Set-Cookie: pres=; expires=Thu, 30-Oct-1980 16:00:00 GMT;domain=.live.com;path=/;version=1
Set-Cookie: LOpt=0; domain=login.live.com;path=/;version=1
Set-Cookie: WLSSC=...cookie goes here...; domain=.live.com;secure= ;path=/;HTTPOnly= ;version=1
Set-Cookie: MSPSoftVis=@72...20@:@; domain=login.live.com;path=/;version=1
PPServer: PPV: 30 H: BAYIDSLGN1M36 V: 0
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2011 09:53:04 GMT
Connection: close

<html><head><script type="text/javascript">function rd(){window.location.replace("http://www.hotmail.msn.com/cgi-bin/sbox?t=...&p=...&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&id=2");}function OnBack(){}</script></head><body onload="javascript:rd();"></body></html></textarea>!!!<textarea>HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Length: 546
Content-Type: text/html
Location: http://www.hotmail.msn.com/cgi%2Dbin/sbox/?t=...&p=...&mkt=EN-US&lc=1033&id=2
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"
xxn: 49
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2011 09:53:04 GMT

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2011 09:53:05 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"
xxn: 16
MSNSERVER: H: DUB102-w16 V: 16.0.1677.630 D: 2011-06-30T23:31:34
Location: http://mail.live.com/default.aspx
Set-Cookie: KVC=...cookie goes here...; domain=.mail.live.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: xid=...cookie goes here...; domain=.msn.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: xidseq=1; domain=.msn.com; path=/
Set-Cookie: LD=; domain=.msn.com; expires=Fri, 08-Jul-2011 08:13:05 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 150

***[according to the normal browser flow, here I should be redirected to the normal hotmail homepage]***

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2011 09:53:05 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
P3P: CP="BUS CUR CONo FIN IVDo ONL OUR PHY SAMo TELo"
xxn: 34
MSNSERVER: H: DUB103-w34 V: 16.0.1677.630 D: 2011-06-30T23:31:34
Location: https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=11&ct=1310118785&rver=6.1.6206.0&wp=MBI&wreply=http:%2F%2Fmail.live.com%2Fdefault.aspx%3Frru%3Dinbox&lc=1033&id=...&mkt=en-US&cbcxt=mai&snsc=1
Set-Cookie: KSC=; domain=.mail.live.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 12:00:01 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: kr=; domain=.mail.live.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 12:00:01 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: bsc=; domain=.mail.live.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 12:00:01 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: rru=; domain=.mail.live.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 12:00:01 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: prc=; domain=.mail.live.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 12:00:01 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: mt=; domain=.mail.live.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 12:00:01 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: KVC=; domain=.mail.live.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 12:00:01 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: DWN=; domain=.mail.live.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 12:00:01 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 354

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 210
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Fri, 08 Jul 2011 09:52:06 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Set-Cookie: MSPRequ=lt=...&id=...&co=1; path=/;version=1
Set-Cookie: MSPSoftVis=@721...620@:@; domain=login.live.com;path=/;version=1
PPServer: PPV: 30 H: BAYIDSLGN1M44 V: 0
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2011 09:53:06 GMT
Connection: close

<html><head><script type="text/javascript">function rd(){window.location.replace("http://mail.live.com/default.aspx?rru=inbox");}function OnBack(){}</script></head><body onload="javascript:rd();"></body></html>


***[from now on if I go to default.aspx?rru=inbox, it will redirect me to the previous login.live.com which will again redirect me to this default.aspx and so on in an endless loop]***
```

Somehow hotmail manages to enter endless loop and I didn't manage to figure out why. All the cookies are saved in a txt file and did make sure that CURL in fact writes to it. I even tried examining it step by step and I think I found out that KVC cookies doesn't get saved. However when I manually parsed it out of headers and inserted into the CURL cookie file, that didn't change anything: I still got this erroneous flow.

Comment: I need to get the contacts from address book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are the site uses an [CSRF](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token to prevent you from doing that. Instead of trying to emulate a login via the website and then scraping the contacts from the Hotmail page use the [Messenger Connect REST API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx). It supports [reading Contact objects from Hotmail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243648.aspx#contact).

> To get a collection of Contact objects by using the Messenger Connect REST API, make a GET request with the following parameters.
>
> ```
> https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?access_token=yourApiKey
> ```

This will return all Contacts in JSON format, which you can easily parse with [`json_decode`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), e.g. do

```
$contacts = json_decode(
    file_get_contents(
        'https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?access_token=yourApiKey'
    )
);
```

Comment: Well, unfortunately the REST API won't exactly fit my needs. It's a good thing and in the end I'll implement it but this will require some time because right now it won't fit well into the current framework (and I need to have this bug fixed somehow).

Comment: I don't understand very well how the token can be a problem here. I sniffed using a FF plugin and checked the exact fields that get passed to hotmail. Then I found where the data for those fields comes from and created an identical request to the sign in form. And still it doesn't work. That's what confuses me so much.

Comment: @Eugene I don't want to help you with that cURL approach. It's not the right approach. It might even be illegal under MS's ToS. And really no offense, but if you cannot exchange the method that does that cURL request with those few lines above to make a REST API call, your framework's design is likely broken.

Comment: That's ok, I understand. Anyway, thanks for the API link. If I don't fix the problem through CURL, I'll use that way.